# Околица, окрестность, округа

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как обозначить ту территорию Подмосковья, которая наиболее удалена от Москвы?

Околица, околоток, округ, окрестности? Я пытаюсь дать представление о территории, повествуя о неких событиях. Будут ли эти понятия включать Подмосковье?

Comment: @shampar Почему "наиболее удалена"? Этого не было в оригинале.

Comment: Потому, что область целиком не может быть удалена от областного города. Так по первоисточнику выходило.

Comment: Она может быть целиком удалена, так как она находится на некотором расстоянии. Даже примыкание - разновидность удаленности, если вы включаете смежные территории.